# Run time error 1004, cannot complete operation

Tags: vba, powerquery

I use VBA to copy one table's content and paste into another table. The codes that I use are:

```
Sub Get_Original_OutPutDataTable()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Input&Map").Activate
    Range("InitialMap").Select
    Selection.Delete
    Worksheets("OutPutDataTable").Activate
    Range("OutPutDataTable").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Input&Map").Activate
    Range("InitialMap").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Both `"InitialMap"` and `"OutPutDataTable"` are two tables created by Power Query.

Sometimes, the codes above work fine. However, if I refresh `"InitialMap"` first, I will run into the error.

[image]

Or another error
[image]

If I run into the second error, the content will be pasted into next row. For example, if `"InitialMap"` starts from cell A4 (Row 4 contains header, table content starts from row 5.), the content will be pasted into cell A6, like this
[image]
Anyone knows why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would replace your InitialMap table with one created as an ordinary Excel Table, not using Power Query.

Excel is trying to protect you from editing a table sourced from Power Query, as your updates will be wiped out if the user Refreshes PQ or Data.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. I would use an alternative solution instead of copying data from one table into another.